# Bitwise not and Logic wise not: Why does "~true == true" and "~false == false"

Tags: c++, boolean, bit-manipulation

I have a question about the `bitwise not` and `logical not` and hopefully someone can answer it for me.

So I know the following works:

```
!true == false
!false == true
```

I thought the `bitwise not` can do the same thing, but it apparently can't.

Suppose I have a boolean:

```
bool test = true;
```

then when I print out `~test`, the output is `true`.

If the boolean is

```
bool test = false;
```

then when I print out `~test`, the output is `true`, which is expected. However, when I do a `~test` again, it does not get back to `false`.

For some reason, the `bitwise not` cannot flip the boolean value from `true` to `false`.

Does anyone have an answer for this?

Comment: true = nonzero (as input usually 1), false = zero. ~true = ~1 = nonzero = true. ~false = ~0 = nonzero = true (although title says false)

Comment: Sounds like a really good reason not to apply `~` to `bool` values. The real answer is: use `!`, not `~`.

Answer (score 8):

According to §5.3.1.10 of the C++ standard ([[expr.unary.op]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#10)), the `~` operator takes an integral (or unscoped enumeration type) operand and performs integral promotions where the type of the result of an `~` operation is the type of its promoted operand. This means that the boolean is first converted to an integral (`0` for `false` and `1` for `true`). Because of your context, the result of the `~` operation is then converted back to a boolean: `false` for `0` and `true` for all non-zero values.

If you have a boolean `x`, you can think of `~x` as `~static_cast<int>(x)` and of `x = ~x` as `x = ((~static_cast<int>(x)) != 0)`.

Hence:

```
bool a = false;
bool b = ~a; // b = (~static_cast<int>(a) != 0)
             // b = (~static_cast<int>(false) != 0)
             // b = (~0 != 0)
             // b = (0xffffffff != 0)
             // b = true
bool c = ~b; // c = (~static_cast<int>(b) != 0)
             // c = (~static_cast<int>(true) != 0)
             // c = (~1 != 0)
             // c = (0xfffffffe != 0)
             // c = true
```

Comment: This doesnt answer why is ~~false  true

Comment: @LukaRahne it absolutely does. You first bitwise not false, which will yield `11...10`, and then cast it to a boolean, resulting in `true`. As he explained, when you go to then use the `~` on `true`, it'll give you true again.

Comment: @LukaRahne: `~~false` has type `int` with value `0`, so it's not true.  schohe001's explanation is talking about something else, it seems.  Your expression doesn't convert `~false` back to a boolean in between `~` operations.  It's just bool->int conversion, then flip the bits, then flip the bits again back to the original.  We can see this with GCC for AVR: https://godbolt.org/z/h6f437ova - `auto foo() { return ~~false; }` loads two 8-bit registers with zero, so we can see the return type was not `bool` (instead `int`.)  As this answer explains, `~(bool)~false` is very different, it's `-2`

Answer (score 3):

The key to understanding what is happening is to realize there are *implicit conversions* going on. The `~` operator is applied to an integer and returns an integer, so the operand must first be converted to integer, and then the result converted to bool before assignment. `false` converts to 0, `true` converts to 1. In the other direction, 0 converts to `false` and *any non-zero value* converts to `true`. `~1` is non-zero, so it is converted to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

1. `true` gets converted to `0x00000001`.
2. `~` does bitwise negation, flipping every bit in the value it's applied to :
   `~0x00000001 == 0xfffffffe`, which is non-0 and therefore evaluates to true.
3. Similarly, `false` goes to `0x00000000`, and `~0x00000000 == 0xffffffff`, which when converted to `bool` becomes `true`.
4. That `true` value, when `~` is applied to it again, is converted back to
   `0x00000001`, not `0xffffffff`, and you're back at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Before applying the operator `~` on a `bool`, a conversion to `int` takes place. Hence, `~true` is `~int(true)`, which is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

Converting `bool` to `int`:

```
true ==> 1
false ==> 0
```

Converting `int` to `bool`:

```
zero value ==> false
non-zero value ==> true
```

From here onwards, the answer to your question is simple:

```
~true == ~1
~1 != 0
~1 == true
```

Your expectation of `~true == false` would work if and only if `true` was converted to `~0`:

```
~true == ~~0
~~0 == 0
0 == false
```